# Run a PHPUnit static test only for the /app folder

Tags: magento2, phpunit

Hi I am trying to Run a PHPUnit **static** test only for the **/app** folder and I do not know how to exclude the /vendor folder not to be tested.

I am using the following command: php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/static/phpunit.xml

If somebody has any idea on how to exclude the /vendor folder and run the static test only in for the /app folder, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can't exclude vendor folder in this scenario. since under vendor folder, it holds some of the basic definitions which is required by a module to be run.

Comment: Thank you John. This clarifies everything. I am a beginner with Magento 2 and I thought that I could run a "PHP Coding Standard Verification "  test to verify the code written in the /app folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by run following command to test your own module

1) Go to your Magento root folder

2) run below command

> ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/Vendor/Module

gte reference from [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/test/unit/unit_test_execution_cli.html)

you can follow below command to run the specific module of vendor directory

> ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/magento/module-catalog

Comment: This will not gonna fit for static tests - the main point that we do not need filter by tests to be executed, but files that should be covered for these tests.